# I cant line up nor vertically align div elements so that they resize automatically

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I need to align a label to a select box side by side. The problem is that the select box will change in height randomly. I want the label to adjust its height and vertically align automatically when the select input resizes. This is what I have so far:

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  display: table;
}
.left {
  float: left;
  width: 40%;
  text-align: right;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.right {
  float: left;
  width: 60%;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
select {
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <span>Guest 1:</span>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <select>
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

I appreciate your help, please let me know if you need more info or more details.
Thank you

UPDATE: I cant use `table` or `form` in the markup

Comment: Just get rid of both floats and it will word. You have containers displayed as table-cells so use instead `text-align: left`

Comment: well that was easy lol.. please place an answer with your comment so that I can give you the green checkmark. thank you

Comment: You don't need to use all that display table stuff. The main issue is you have two different elements with different heights and line-heights. See answer below. You might run into some issue with disabling your floats if you want multiple labels and form elements on a single line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just get rid of both floats and it will work. You have containers displayed as table-cells so use instead `text-align: left`

Answer (score 0):

You have some extra CSS properties that you don't really need like all the display table related ones. The main culprit here is that your label DIV has a different height that your SELECT list. As long as you don't have multiple lines of text in your label then the easiest and most likely solution is to set your label's height equal to that of the SELECT list. The way you want to do that is to use the `line-height` property equal to the height of the SELECT list as I have done below.

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
}
.container > div {
  float: left;
}
.left {
  width: 40%;
  text-align: right;
  line-height: 30px;
}
.right {
  width: 60%;
}
select {
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <span>Guest 1:</span>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <select>
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but `line-height` will not work because if I were to add longer text in the label rather than "Guest 1", it will  continue onto another line and throw everything off.

Comment: Yes, I mentioned that in my answer.